# $_POST not working on some fields

Tags: php, post

I was working on the email of PHP where 5 form fields will retried and sent in a mail. I got some code to achieve this where code was only written for 4 text fields and I have 5 text fields. The problem is the $_POST is not retrieving the 5th field value, even if I place it in different order it is not retrieving the value.
Below are the code and results.

letusknow.php File:

```
<div class="row">

            <form id="enquiryForm" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
                <fieldset>

                <!-- Form Name -->
                <legend>Free Quote</legend>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Name</label>  
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                  <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" class="form-control input-md" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Name.">

                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Email</label>  
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                  <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email ID" class="form-control input-md" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Email Id.">

                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Mobile</label>  
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                  <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Enter your mobile number" class="form-control input-md" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Phone Number.">

                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-2 control-label">City</label>  
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                  <input id="city" name="city" type="text" placeholder="Enter your city" class="form-control input-md" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your City.">

                  </div>
                </div>

                                <!-- Prepended text-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Product Loan Amount</label>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon">(INR) ₹</span>
                      <input id="productLoan" name="productLoan" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter product loan amount" type="number" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter the Product Loan Amount.">
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Multiple Checkboxes -->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="checkboxIAuthorize"></label>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="checkbox">
                    <label for="checkboxIAuthorize-0">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxIAuthorize-0" value="">
                      I authorize to contact me
                    </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- For success/fail messages -->
                <div id="success"></div>

                <!-- Button -->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                  </div>
                </div>

                </fieldset>
                </form>
        </div>
```

enquiry_mail.php File:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email_address = $_POST["email"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$city = $_POST["city"];
$loan = $_POST["productLoan"];

// create email body and send it    
$to = 'support@mysampledomain.com'; // PUT YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS HERE
$email_subject = "Enquiry Contact Form:  $name"; // EDIT THE EMAIL SUBJECT LINE HERE
$email_body = "You have received a new enquiry from your website's Enquiry form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\nName: $name\nPhone: $phone\nEmail: $email_address\nCity: $city\nProduct Loan Amount: $loan";
$headers = "From: $email_address\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

After I executed the mail is sent to the support@mysampledomain.com and it has below result.

```
You have received a new enquiry from your website's Enquiry form.

Here are the details:
Name: TestName
Phone: 9191919191
Email: testname@testsample.com
City: Test City
Product Loan Amount:
```

Here the Product Loan Amount is not retried with value. The $_POST is failed.
Help me with the issue.

Comment: Firstly, it's somewhat suprising that you're getting `$_POST` data from a form that seems to be sending a `GET` request. Secondly, did you try using lowercase only for the name of the last element

Comment: Also try to hard code a product loan amount and see if that gets sent

Comment: As @adeneo said, try to use only lowercase in indexes (and HTML `name` attribute). Also, please do some validating and filtering on inputs.

Comment: @adeneo I have changed the name giving in lowercase and i didn't work out.

Comment: @Blu3 I have tried hardcoding the value using val="20000" in last field but it didn't return in the $_POST method.

Comment: I tried many ways and found only the $_POST is not working on the 5th field. Guys please help me on this issue.

Comment: Try this code:
<?php if(isset($_POST["productLoan"])){
     $to = 'support@mysampledomain.com';
$email_subject = "Enquiry Contact Form:  $name"; 
$email_body = "You have received a new enquiry from your website's Enquiry form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\nName: $name\nPhone: $phone\nEmail: $email_address\nCity: $city\nProduct Loan Amount: $loan";
$headers = "From: $email_address\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;     
}else{
echo "Error, post not found";
}

Answer (score 0):

Set The form method to POST

I tried

```
<input value="200" id="productLoan" name="productLoan" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter product loan amount" type="number" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter the Product Loan Amount.">
```

and it is printing the result of 200

but when you type a string on the field productLoan and try to post it
it will not post the value since the type of the field is number

hope you get what i mean